# Git how to remove conflict markers from files?

Tags: git

```
>>>>>>> master
      .row
        - @power.next_invoice.tap do |invoice|

        %p
          = link_to t(".postings"), postings_path
<<<<<<< HEAD
    .span9{style: 'margin-top: 50px;'}
=======
    .span9
>>>>>>> master
```

Somehow these master and head comments/code have been added all over my code in all files.
How do I remove them?

Comment: Were these brought in with your last pull from master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you have a merge conflict between two commits in your git repository.

You can either use a mergetool, or you can manually delete these instances (if your editor allows for search and replace, search for instances of `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `>>>>>>> master` to delete them)

In your example, I can see there you have a duplicate code here -

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    .span9{style: 'margin-top: 50px;'}
=======
    .span9
>>>>>>> master
```

You have to decide if your wan `.span9{style: 'margin-top: 50px;'}` or if you want `.span9` (I am assuming you have more css definitions below that). And delete the other option accordingly. `======` should also be removed.

Once you have made your decision, you should run

```
git status
```

which will show you that you have updated this particular css file and chances are you will also have a `.orig` copy of this file created by git.  Delete the `.orig` file, and git add/commit to complete your merge conflict resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Those indicate areas where Git wasn't able to automatically merge your code. For example, this sections shows differences between your `HEAD` (top) and `master` (bottom) for the `.span9` css style.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    .span9{style: 'margin-top: 50px;'}
=======
    .span9
>>>>>>> master
```

You will need to edit your files to manually merge them by choosing either your code, the merged code, or a combination of the two, and then commit your changes.

Read more about [Git Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Answer (score 2):

This tells you were the difference is. You can delete the old code / change it altogheter and remove those lines. Then the conflict should be resolved

Comment: You would still need need the re-add the file(s) to the index again

Comment: like after every change